# How to add Microsoft CDO for Exchange 2000 Library in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am trying to embed a picture file in my html string and send out the email using VB6.

I need to use this function `AddRelatedBodyPart` in the library of Microsoft CDO for Exchange 2000 Library.

Can someone please help me to install this library in VB6. Thanks

Comment: what is that? is this a marlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need MAPI for Exchange 2000: `MSMAPI32.OCX` and `cdosys.dll`.

If you don't find such an old installer, may be googling on the net you will be able to find the correct version of this two files. Then, copy and register this two files by hand:

For example: `regsvr32 %windir%\system32\cdosys.dll`

A note *aside*: On a 64-bit version of Windows operating system, there are two versions of the Regsv32.exe file:

- The 64-bit version is %systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe.
- The 32-bit version is %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe.

Be sure to use the 32bit version.

To test the successfully installation, in the VBIDE go to Project->References and add "Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library".

Now, press F2 to open the Object Browser. You should be able to find the function you need.

[image]